# Cancel duplicate call if event not finished

Tags: c#, events

I have got a list with elements in it, every element has got it's own `swipeEvent`.
And within that element it creates a new obj to the list. like shown below

```
 public Object inserPages(BoxView boxview, List<T> list)
 {
     count++;

     Object obj = new Object();
     Object obj2 = new Object();

     obj.Swiped += (s, e) =>
     {
          obj.TranslateTo(-1200, 0, 500, null);
          obj2.TranslateTo(-1200, 0, 500, null);

          list.Insert(0, boxview);

          list.Insert(1, inserPages(boxview, list));

     };

     return obj;
}
```

Now I need to make some sort of way to disable all the others objects swiped event while the called event is still running.

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Comment: This can't be a real problem.  An UI event like "swipe" simply cannot fire when an event handler is occupying the UI thread.  If, somehow, there are threads involved so this event *could* be fired from multiple threads then you must use at least a lock to protect that List<>.  Monitor.TryEnter() is then the obvious way to "disable" the event.  Very unlikely, do avoid trying to solve a non-existing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `bool` flag:

```
private bool isSwipping;

public Object inserPages(BoxView boxview, List<T> list)
{   
    // ...

    obj.Swiped += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (isSwipping)
            return;

        isSwipping = true;

        // do something

        isSwipping = false;
    };

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Tried that. But i thinking that maybe it's 
`obj.TranslateTo(-1200, 0, 500, null); obj2.TranslateTo(-1200, 0, 500, null);` thats is the sinner here. Those two are awaitable,. and i wanna make them do the animation on the same time. cures obj2 is like a border frame for the first obj. Like a rectangle in a rectangle just to give the inner rectangle a border

Comment: @DaCh: it is better to provide all known details in the question. Looking at your code it is hard to say, that it could be a multi-threading issue.

Comment: i see you point. but since that would require a lot more explaining. And that this answer did answer what i asked for. i think it would be better to make this the answer, and then i will open a other thread with a better descriptions of what my problem is